# Is there a name for this point?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I found the following problem interesting:

In a three villages $A$, $B$ and $C$ there are $a,b$ and $c$ pupils respectively. Where should one build the school such that the total length of pupils going to the school is as small as possible?

How one could solve it as there are no coordinates of villages given?

Comment: So you want to locate $S$ which minimizes $\sum_ja_jd(S,A_j)$, with $a_j$ students coming from the village at $A_j$.

Comment: This seem pretty much analogous to finding the center of mass of three point particles.

Comment: If I'm not wrong it is called Torichelli-Steiner point.

Answer (score 0):

This is Fermat point. See the link below

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point

For weighted sum, it is usually called weighted Fermat point. Make a search on google.

Comment: I don't see an analogy for that point as there are weights $a,b,c$ in my problem

Comment: @curious just add the adjective "weight" to whatever name you prefer.